# Random number is not refreshed on submit

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a random number generator (for voucher numbers), but when I click the button, a new random number is not shown. Can anyone help please?

This is my controller that generates the random number:

```
   static Random random = new Random();
   public List<string> RandomVouchers()
    { 
        int vouchersToGenerate = 1;
        int lengthOfVoucher = 10;
        List<string> generatedVouchers = new List<string>();
        char[] keys = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890".ToCharArray();

        while (generatedVouchers.Count < vouchersToGenerate)
        {
            string voucher = GenerateVoucher(keys, lengthOfVoucher);
            if (!generatedVouchers.Contains(voucher))
            {
                 generatedVouchers.Add(voucher);
                 return generatedVouchers; 
            }
        }
        return generatedVouchers;
    }

    private static string GenerateVoucher(char[] keys, int lengthOfVoucher)
    {
        return Enumerable
            .Range(1, lengthOfVoucher) // for(i.. ) 
            .Select(k => keys[random.Next(0, keys.Length - 1)])  // generate a new random char 
            .Aggregate("", (e, c) => e + c); // join into a string
    }
```

This  is the orders page :

```
<div id="vouchercode" style="display:none">
<ul>
    @foreach (string strVouchers in ViewBag.Vouchers)
    {
        <li>@strVouchers</li>
    }
</ul></div>
<button id="getvoucher">GenerateVoucher</button>
```

This is javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#getvoucher").click(function () {
        $("#vouchercode").dialog({
            width: 460,
            height: 200,
            modal: true,
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Your javascript only opens a dialog box, there is no call to the controller either using ajax or form-submit.

Comment: when i refresh the page or use location.reload(); it gives me different random numbers but not only refreshing

Comment: Every time page reloads, the controller runs to generate a view, hence a different random number. To generate them on a button click, you need to explicitly call the controller using ajax and generate the number while maintaining the view.